# Gmail mobile mailto: Subject and Body using - https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/80/#co

Tags: mobile, gmail, message, mailto

I am able to construct a prepopulated message with Gmail using:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&ui=2&tf=0&fs=1&to=&su=Subject&body=Body

It works great on PC and however it works on mobile, it is very small and require the user to zoom and scroll around in order to view or edit the message before sending it.

I am seeking a solution to do the same using the following URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/80/#co

The latter URL display much better on mobile devices. 
Does anyone know how I could go about to prepopulate the Subject and Body for this (mobile) version?